# Usage guidance for the tag "President"

Tags: discussion, tags

The currently most used tag without a tag usage guidance is [president](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/president) (100 questions).

Many countries in the world have a president. But after looking at a few of the questions tagged with it, I noticed that most of them apply specifically to the President of the United States (There might be a bit bias at the moment due to the upcoming US presidential election).

On the other hand we also have the [congress](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/congress) tag where the usage guideline says that it is specifically about the "the **U.S.** legislative body". There [are other congresses in the world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congress#Congresses_within_nations) which have a similar function, but apparently the community doesn't consider them nearly as interesting as the US congress.

So what do we do with the tag usage guidance. Do we use the tag specifically for the POTUS or for presidents in general all around the world? If the latter, should we create a new tag [us-president](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-president) and start retagging most of the 100 questions currently tagged with president?

Comment: Yet another problem is that the [tag:president] is highly abused; many questions do not deserve the tag because *"Tags should help to describe what the question is about, not just what it contains."*

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to user4012, I think we should go for specific tags.

The tag are meant to indicate what the question is about. And a simple rule to see the validity of a tag, is to use the sentence:

> I am a specialist of *tag-name*

While some people might consider themselves specialists of US-presidents. I doubt anyone would consider that their specialities extend to all existing presidents from all the countries in the world.

On P.SE there's a bit of bias towards the USA generally. And these days, with the upcoming election, it shows even more. But nevertheless, [president](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/president) should not mean specifically POTUS. And I think that the tag as such should be suppressed. Possibly with an alias.

Same goes for [congress](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/congress).

Comment: In this case, how do we handle questions about the Presidents of other countries? Wouldn't the users who consider themselves specialists of president-of-their-home-country demand for individual tags, and we end up with 193 of those?

Comment: If you can address @bytebuster's concern, i'd be tempted to support your proposal, since that concern is the main driving reason for me to propose what I did in my answer.

Comment: @user4012, well first, there aren't 193 presidents, since not all countries have one. Second, currently, [tag:president] is used exclusively for US ones, which means that the likelihood of having questions about the President of Gabon is very low. Then most questions about presidents aren't about presidents themselves but about their elections. So it's essentially a non-problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. We shouldn't have a tag [us-president](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-president)

   Compound tags are a Bad Idea overall (i'd rather not waste space explaining why in this answer, but if needed we can discuss that on a separate post).

   Instead, questions about US President/POTUS should simply have [us](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us) + [president](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/president) if needed.
2. As such, [president](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/president) should be expanded and encompass all countries, with approach listed in #1 (country tags) used if the question is about a President of a specific country.

Same goes for [congress](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/congress)

Comment: I'm OK with the idea of making "potus" and "us-president" tag aliases for "president", to make tagging easier for newbies.